# Which Linux I should use in it?

Tags: lubuntu, login, 64-bit, 32-bit, windows-xp

**I have a old laptop of windows xp in it of ram 1gb and 160gb of hard disk but I think it's 32bit.** First I install lubuntu but I can not be able to open it, as it show black screen with a blinking dash. Now I want to know what should I do. I am very confused now. Suggest a easy setup linux os.

Comment: There are no 32-bit versions of Ubuntu that are still supported on this site. That said, [the Legacy (32-bit) version of Bodhi Linux](https://www.bodhilinux.com/download/) is pretty decent for people using older machines. It's based on Ubuntu 18.04 but, if you have questions, you'll need a different forum 

Comment: You should first work out if your box is *i386* (32-bit) or *amd64* (64-bit; AMD created the compatible 64-bit architecture that was backwards compatible so even intel CPUs are amd64).   Few winXP desktops are i386; though early laptops were (esp. before 2005) & low-end even later.  Also note it doesn't matter what your windows was; as 32-bit windows was $5 cheaper which consumers understood more readily than 32vs64 bits; thus most 64-bit hardware sold with 32-bit windows (*when geared for consumers not enterprise*)

Comment: @matigo Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is *i386* or 32-bit & still on-topic.  Server & Netboot ISOs exist & allow Desktop to be installed (just no ISOs were produced except for *flavors*).

Comment: If you want help with Lubuntu - you need to provide specific details; what release of Lubuntu; did you verify the ISO prior to write to installation media? verify write to media? as per manual? What did you try? etc. You've given no specifics that I can respond to with regards Lubuntu.  I used laptops with [RAM] specs as you mentioned in QA-testing Lubuntu up to 19.04 (2019-April release). but as stated I'd first work out if your hardware is x86 (*i386*) or x86_64 (*amd64*); I still use 80GB drives today for some QA-tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install the LXLE distribution that you may download at this link (https://www.lxle.net/download/). It supports the 32 bit architecture.
The distribution is a fork of Lubuntu but it has a large supported hardware, mainly for old systems.
Otherwise, you can try to download an older version of Linux Lite which can support 32 bit. For example the first old version is the 3.8 one (the download is available at this link
https://osdn.net/projects/linuxlite/storage/3.8/linux-lite-3.8-32bit.iso/)

Try them!